# Android Studio Google Maps Clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, markerclusterer

I have 30 000 Markers inside my map and i tried Cluestering them like Google,up to here all good.
The problem is when i zoom a specific area the markers unclustered not only inside that area but in all the maps and when i unzoom all markers render on my map slowing down

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i also have the same problem, showing 32k markers. they said to decide a zoom value where clustering is disabled in the Renderer shouldRenderCluster something overridden method. but i still think the clustering has limitations. i dont mind if max zoom doesnt decluster the markers. the important thing is that when they get clustered, it shouldnt happen like what you showed above.